Web Server in C++: Server Class
Planning on writing a set of blog articles on how to write a webs server.
So each phase will have a new version of the server with extra features. But starting very basic and working up to a reasonable (not apache good) server written in C++ that people can take and play with.
Before I go and show the code in an article I hope I can get some feedback here to make sure I don't do anything to stupid.
Version 3: Server Class
Version 2 started to test my bounds in having all the code in one file. So I am going to use this version to distribute the code into multiple classes. So that in subsequent articles I don't need to show code that is not changing.
Lets do the things that are not going to change much first:
Nissa.cpp
Server is called "Nissa" after Scandinavian Folklore.
#include "Server.h"
#include "PintHTTP.h"

#include <ThorsLogging/ThorsLogging.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    loguru::g_stderr_verbosity = 9;

    std::cout << PACKAGE_STRING << " Server\n";

    int port = 8080;
    if (argc > 1) {
      port = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    }

    using ThorsAnvil::Nissa::Server;
    using ThorsAnvil::Nissa::PintHTTP;

  PintHTTP    pintHTTP;

#define CERTIFICATE_INFO    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/thorsanvil.dev/"

#ifdef CERTIFICATE_INFO
    // If you have site certificate set CERTIFICATE_INFO to the path
    // This will then create an HTTPS server.
    using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo;
    CertificateInfo certificate{CERTIFICATE_INFO "fullchain.pem",
                                CERTIFICATE_INFO "privkey.pem"
                               };
    Server          server{certificate, port, pintHTTP};
#else
    // Without a site certificate you should only use an HTTP port.
    // But most modern browsers are going to complain.
    // See: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/
    //      On how to get a free signed site certificate.
    Server          server{port, pintHTTP};
#endif

    server.run();
}

Pint.h
Which means the things they work with are "Pints" as the scoundrals like a tipple over Christmas.
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSA_PINT_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSA_PINT_H


#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
#include <functional>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa
{

enum class PintResult {Done, More};

class Pint
{
    public:
        using SocketStream = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;
        using ServerAction = std::function<bool(SocketStream&&)>;

        virtual ~Pint() {}
        virtual PintResult handleRequest(SocketStream& stream)    = 0;
};

}

#endif

PintHTTP.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSA_PINT_HTTP_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSA_PINT_HTTP_H

#include "Pint.h"

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa
{

class PintHTTP: public Pint
{
    using SocketStream = Pint::SocketStream;
    using ServerAction = Pint::ServerAction;

    public:
        virtual PintResult handleRequest(SocketStream& stream) override;
};

}

#endif

PintHTTP.cpp
#include "PintHTTP.h"
#include <charconv>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa;

PintResult PintHTTP::handleRequest(SocketStream& stream)
{
    std::size_t bodySize = 0;
    bool        closeSocket = true;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(stream, line))
    {
        std::cout << "Request: " << line << "\n";
        if (line == "\r") {
            break;
        }
        if (line == "Connection: keep-alive\r") {
            closeSocket = false;
        }
        if (line.compare("Content-Length: ") == 0) {
            std::from_chars(&line[0] + 16, &line[0] + line.size(), bodySize);
        }
    }
    stream.ignore(bodySize);

    if (stream)
    {
        stream << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
               << "Content-Length: 135\r\n"
               << "\r\n"
               << R"(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Nissa server 1.1</title></head>
<body>Hello world</body>
</html>)";
        stream.flush();
    }
    std::cerr << "Done\n";
    return closeSocket ? PintResult::Done : PintResult::More;
}

JobQueue.h
The first interesting piece of code that pops out is the JobQueue. This basically controls the background threads that processes any accepted request.
I am deliberately keeping this class simple as I know that the next step is going to involve storing some state. So I don't want any state in the queue explicitly. So the JobQueue holds only actions that need to be taken.
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSA_JOB_QUEUE_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSA_JOB_QUEUE_H

#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa
{

using Work    = std::function<void()>;
class JobQueue
{
    using WorkQueue     = std::queue<Work>;

    std::vector<std::thread>        workers;
    std::mutex                      workMutex;
    std::condition_variable         workCV;
    WorkQueue                       workQueue;

    public:
        JobQueue(int workerCount);
        ~JobQueue();

        void addJob(Work&& action);

    private:
        Work     getNextJob();
        void     processWork();
};
}
#endif

JobQueue.cpp
#include "JobQueue.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa;

JobQueue::JobQueue(int workerCount)
{
    for (int loop = 0; loop < workerCount; ++loop) {
        workers.emplace_back(&JobQueue::processWork, this);
    }
}

JobQueue::~JobQueue()
{
    for (auto& worker: workers) {
        worker.join();
    }
}

void JobQueue::addJob(Work&& action)
{
    std::unique_lock    lock(workMutex);
    workQueue.emplace(std::move(action));
    workCV.notify_one();
}

Work JobQueue::getNextJob()
{
    std::unique_lock    lock(workMutex);
    workCV.wait(lock, [&](){return !workQueue.empty();});
    Work work = std::move(workQueue.front());
    workQueue.pop();
    return work;
}

void JobQueue::processWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Work work   = getNextJob();
        work();
    }
}

Server.h
This leaves a very simple Server class definition.
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSA_SERVER_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSA_SERVER_H

#include "Pint.h"
#include "JobQueue.h"

#include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa
{

class Server
{
    using SSLctx        = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLctx;
    using Listener      = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Server;
    using SocketStream  = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream;
    using CertificateInfo = ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::CertificateInfo;
    SSLctx                          ctx;
    Listener                        listener;
    Pint&                           pint;
    JobQueue                        jobQueue;

    public:
        Server(int port, Pint& pint, int workerCount = 1);
        Server(CertificateInfo& certificate, int port, Pint& pint, int workerCount = 1);

        void run();
    private:
        void        connectionHandler(SocketStream& stream);
};

}

#endif

Server.cpp
#include "Server.h"

#include <ThorsSocket/Socket.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nissa;

Server::Server(int port, Pint& pint, int workerCount)
    : ctx{ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType::Server}
    , listener{ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::ServerInfo{port}}
    , pint{pint}
    , jobQueue{workerCount}
{}

Server::Server(CertificateInfo& certificate, int port, Pint& pint, int workerCount)
    : ctx{ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SSLMethodType::Server, certificate}
    , listener{ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SServerInfo{port, ctx}}
    , pint{pint}
    , jobQueue{workerCount}
{}

template<typename T>
struct CopyOnMove
{
    mutable T   value;
    CopyOnMove(T&& init)
        : value(std::move(init))
    {}
    CopyOnMove(CopyOnMove const& copy)
        : value{std::move(copy.value)}
    {}
};

void Server::run()
{
    using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Socket;
    using ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::Blocking;

    while (true)
    {
        Socket          accept = listener.accept(Blocking::No);
        SocketStream    stream(std::move(accept));
        jobQueue.addJob([&, StreamRef = CopyOnMove{std::move(stream)}]() mutable
        {
            SocketStream stream{std::move(StreamRef.value)};
            connectionHandler(stream);
        });
    }
}

void Server::connectionHandler(ThorsAnvil::ThorsSocket::SocketStream& stream)
{
    for (bool closeSocket = false; !closeSocket && stream.good();)
    {
        closeSocket = true;
        if (pint.handleRequest(stream) == PintResult::More) {
            closeSocket = false;
        }
    }
}


Naming
While I can see you like the Scandinavian mythology, and having a unique name for your library (ThorsAnvil) is a good thing, please don't take it too far. "Nissa" doesn't mean anything to people outside of Scandinavia, and actually it's called a "nisse" in most Scandinavian countries I know of (also, "pynt" instead of "pint"). Even then I don't think anyone would associate a nisse with a webserver. Consider that ThorsAnvil::Nissa::PintHTTP would translate into something like ThorsAnvil::Gnome::DecorationHTTP.
What is part of the blog and what not?
You already have an existing library, and are building the web server on top of that. But then you put the web server code inside namespace ThorsAnvil as well. That makes it hard to see what is already part of ThorsAnvil and what not.
Is the blog about showing how someone else could write a web server on top of your library, or about showing how you are implementing a web server feature into your own library?
Move JobQueue out of namespace Nissa
A job queue is something that is useful outside of a web server, and you can also see from your code that it has nothing web server related in it.
Job queue improvements

Use std::jthread instead of std::thread if you can, it will join automatically on destruction, and allows you to pass a stop token to the workers.
Add a way for the workers to actually stop. At the moment processWork() is just an infinite loop, and join() will never return.
Call notify_one() without holding the mutex.

Why did you need class Pint?
There is only one class inheriting from Pint, and that's PintHTTP. Why do you need the base class at all?
Consider using std::move_only_function
You need CopyOnMove to work around the issue of adding a lambda that captures a move-only value to the job queue. However, since C++23 you can avoid that issue by using std::move_only_function.
Simplify the loop in connectionHandler()
Instead of using the variable closeSocket, consider rewriting the loop to:
while (stream.good()) {
    if (pint.handleRequest(stream) != PintResult::More) {
        break;
    }
}


actually it's called a "nisse": Poop. You know how much git renaming that means. :-)

Everything I do is inside namespace ThorsAnvil. I have the domain thorsanvil.dev. Then each project is a namespace under that.

Why do you need the base class at all? Because I want to create other protocols.

Nive: std::move_only_function.

Maybe you want to create other protocols, but why already introduce the base class at this point in your blog series? I would just make it a concrete class to avoid unnecessary complication at this point. See also YAGNI.
